# Authantication returning false Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel

I'm writing a simple authentication form with laravel.
After trying two different tutorials, it's still returning false.
Register is working fine, but my login isn't.
Here is the LoginController:

```
        public function getLogin() {
            $this->layout->content = View::make('user.login');
    }

    public function postSignin() {
            if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password'))))
            {
                return Redirect::to('user/dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
            } 
            else 
            {
                return Redirect::to('user/login')
                    ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
                    ->withInput();
            }
    }

    public function getDashboard() {
            $this->layout->content = View::make('user.dashboard');
    }
```

The route:

```
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

and the view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'user/signin', 'class'=>'form-signin')) }}
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Login</h2>

{{ Form::text('username', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Username')) }}
{{ Form::password('password', array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Password')) }}

{{ Form::submit('Login', array('class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary btn-block'))}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I hadn't set a key with

```
php artisan key:generate
```

and my password field was only 32 characters long instead of 60.
Finally got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

In your form you have an input for `username` but in your controller you have `Input::get('email')`.

You have to edit your form like that...

```
{{ Form::text('email', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Username')) }}
```

...**or** your controller like that

```
Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('username'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))
```